# want to create dynamic url

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforcedx

```
<aura:component controller='CaseAttachment' implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,force:hasRecordId" access="global">
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="ID"/>
<aura:attribute name="attachmentList" type="Attachment[]" />
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.displayAttach}"/> 

<lightning:card title="Attachment">
    <center> 
        <lightning:button label="Attach file">
                                    <aura:iteration items="{!v.attachmentList}" var="at"> 
                                 <a href="{'/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid='+at.ParentId+:&parentname;,='+at.Parent.Name+'&retURL=%2F'+at.ParentId}" target ="_blank">Attach file</a>
            </aura:iteration>
        </lightning:button>
    </center>
```

> Failed to save CustomAttachmentRelatedList.cmp: c:CustomAttachmentRelatedList:10,101: ParseError at [row,col]:[11,101] Message: The entity "parentname" was referenced, but not declared.: Source

i want to create dynamic URL and while saving this I'm getting above error

my URL should look like this

> https://garvitab2bsc--44dev.cs60.my.salesforce.com/p/attach/NoteAttach?pid=5003C000003bdmt&parentname=0114054744&retURL=%2F5003C000003bdmtQAA where ‘500..’ is case id, ‘001’ is the case number

Comment: P.S. [the ui elements are being retired soon](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_aura_ui_deprecate.htm). Make sure you're moving to the newer lightning elements.

Comment: ohkay thanks! how can i create dynamic URL from lightning button any idea?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I'm not getting how can i achieve this with the controller  I know I can do like this  href="{!'/'+att.Id+'/'+'e?retURL=%2F'+att.ParentId}" but how this will come when button is clicked

Comment: You would pass in the data as attributes on the component, then you can read those values to construct the URL. Or you could just build the URL as you've done here, then read that in the controller.